# decaf threads vs boost threads vs omnithreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, architecture, libraries

I'm thinking about which threading library to use for a relatively small C++ project that has to run on x86, x86_64 and powerpc architectures.

The project is using ActiveMQ, which provides the decaf::lang::Thread and decaf::util::concurrent facilities. I have no experience with this library and cannot find any tutorial/examples, only documentation?

Has one of you guys/girls ever worked with decaf threading? Can you tell me your experiences and do a little comparison to other products you know?

Thank you,
bb

Comment: I have exactly the same question, for exactly the same reason (using ActiveMQ CPP library).  I need to be sure code within my onMessage callback is synchronized.  I'm guessing that onMessage will be running inside a decaf thread, so I should use decaf thread techniques for synchronization?  (Would be nice not to have to be guessing.)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like ActiveMQ's `decaf::util::concurrent` facilities are pretty nice in that they provide some concurrent containers and a thread pool facility, but I'd still probably vote for using `boost::thread` since it appears to be *much* more well-documented, unless you can anticipate a situation where your threads would need to actually conform to the ActiveMQ thread type signature, but after some quick searching I can't find a lot of indication that that would be necessary. `boost::thread` is pretty mature, very portable, very feature-complete and has the bonus of being very well-documented.

Comment: Realize this is an old thread (really, no pun intended!) but I have the same question.  See my comment above for why I think maybe I DO need to use the Decaf thread utilities in my code.  (At this point in time, I'd rather use the C++ standard library <thread> utilities.)